# U4vl Streaming to multiple web clients

Tags: camera, uv4l, webrtc

I am using uv4l-raspicam and the uv4l-server with WebRTC support, and I am able to stream the image of my camera to one single viewer of the website. The other viewers get an error message that there is already a session running.

However, is it possible to stream from the same camera to multiple web browsers via WebRTC?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stream the camera to more than one peer (e.g. browsers) at the same time you need a SFU or MCU. One supported by UV4L is Janus Gateway. Both UV4L and Janus are pre-installed in this [DEMO OS](https://www.linux-projects.org/rpi-videoconference-demo-os/).

Comment: Thank you. Hm. As far as I see, I would need to write a new plugin for Janus to just use it for broadcasting (the closest thing seems to be the screensharing-test, but it still would require the publisher to run a browser). Are there any alternative MCUs that might be able to do that without writing a new plugin?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your comment. You need to broadcast one camera from the Rpi ("the publisher" in Janus terms) to more viewers (the "listeners"), right? When used as a publisher-only UV4L can push the stream to a Janus videoroom (it does not require any browser to do this). I think you can just configure the room to have a max number of publishers equal to 1 and/or slightly modify the videoroom.js for the listeners not to allow them to also publish their video.