# UV4L wont allow multiple users on .mjpeg stream

Tags: camera, uv4l

I'm trying to make a survaillance system with UV4L i already succeed to play i live streaming and record the live stream from UV4L the problem is that when UV4L detects more than 3 users it blocks the other users.

I'm using a basic html to access the stream like

```
<img src="http://raspberry:8080/stream/video.mjpeg">
```

I was wonder if there's a way i could allow more than 3 users because when i'm recording in the same link although it is from local host it count as a user.

I already check [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76680/u4vl-streaming-to-multiple-web-clients) solution but it seems the problem is diferent i'm not trying to use the video room but just access the stream from the video.mjpeg.

what i need to change is this: `max. simultaneous streams allowed: 3, max. threads: 5`. this info is on the webRTC interface when you are in the server info, as you can see it says it can only stream 3 users at a time.